# Ubuntu 20.04 Snapd Barrier Autostart Client

Tags: snap, autostart

I was having issues auto starting Barrier Client on Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.
I use this desktop as my secondary non Windows desktop for non-secure work stuff thus I have it set to auto login. If you do not have it setup to auto login then you will first have to login to the desktop for it to auto connect.

The following steps are what I took to get it working.

1. Open the Ubuntu Software app
2. Click the Magnifying glass in the upper left top bar
3. Search for Barrier
4. Chose and installed the latest Snapd Barrier version 2.3.3-2 **(You can tell once you click on the app in the store that it is the Snapd version)**
5. Once installed open Barrier from the Applications menu **(Bottom left corner)**
6. Get it connected with your server. In my case a Windows 10 desktop to control it
7. Once you have it up and running and connected you want to find the full command that is running and working with the following command from Terminal

```
ps aux|grep barrier
casey       2167  0.4  0.0 134984  8844 ?        Sl   11:30   0:00 /snap/barrier/384/usr/bin/barrierc -f --no-tray --debug INFO --name MYSCREENNAME --enable-crypto [IPOFSERVER]:24800
```

With that information I then did the following

8. Open Startup Applications to create a new Startup app
9. Click Add
10. Put this in the Command: box **(The path is not the same as above and needed to be changed to /snap/bin/barrier.barrierc)**

```
/snap/bin/barrier.barrierc -f --no-tray --debug INFO --name MYSCREENNAME --enable-crypto [IPOFSERVER]:24800
```

11. Click Save and Reboot

After reboot it should start up and connect to your Barrier server once logged in.
Again in my case I have it auto login my user. If you don't have auto login setup you will need to login first on the local keyboard then it will load the startup we configured.

I found details that got me closer to resolving this from this thread.
[Setting up barrier to run on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201728/setting-up-barrier-to-run-on-startup)
Thanks to [Casper042](https://askubuntu.com/users/905088/casper042) for the help identifying the correct command to get it working.
My rep points are too low to comment or upvote your answer on that thread so I made this one.

Hope this helps someone else.